# Convert table result to a form of JSON

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to form json from a table result set :

```
create table testmalc(
appid int identity(1,1),
propertyid1 int ,
propertyid1val varchar(10) ,
propertyid2 int,
propertyid2val varchar(10) ,
 ) 

insert into testmalc values(456,'t1',789,'t2')

insert into testmalc values(900,'t3',902,'t4')
```

[image]

need below desired JSON result  :

```
{
    "data": {
        "record": [{
                "id": appid,
                "customFields": [{
                        "customfieldid": propertyid1 ,
                        "customfieldvalue": propertyid1val 
                    },
                    {
                        "customfieldid": propertyid2 ,
                        "customfieldvalue": propertyid2val 
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": appid,
                "customFields": [{
                        "customfieldid": propertyid1 ,
                        "customfieldvalue": propertyid1val 
                    },
                    {
                        "customfieldid": propertyid2 ,
                        "customfieldvalue": propertyid2val
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am trying to use `stuff` but was not getting the desired result. Now trying with `UnPivot`.

Comment: Would be easier to do this in an application rather than in the db.

Comment: Is there a chance to upgrade to SQL-Server 2016? We have JSON support there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot upgrade to SQL-Server 2016 for JSON support you should try to solve this in any application / programming language you know of.

Just for fun, I provide an approach, which works, but is more a hack than a solution:

Your test data:

```
DECLARE @testmalc table (
appid int identity(1,1),
propertyid1 int ,
propertyid1val varchar(10) ,
propertyid2 int,
propertyid2val varchar(10)
);

insert into @testmalc values(456,'t1',789,'t2')
                           ,(900,'t3',902,'t4');
```

--create a XML, which is the most similar structure and read it as a `NVARCHAR` string

```
DECLARE @intermediateXML NVARCHAR(MAX)=
(
SELECT t.appid AS id
      ,(
        SELECT t2.propertyid1 AS [prop1/@customfieldid]
              ,t2.propertyid1val AS [prop1/@customfieldvalue]
              ,t2.propertyid2 AS [prop2/@customfieldid]
              ,t2.propertyid2val AS [prop2/@customfieldvalue]
        FROM @testmalc t2 
        WHERE t2.appid=t.appid
        FOR XML PATH('customFields'),TYPE
       ) AS [*]
FROM @testmalc t
GROUP BY t.appid
FOR XML PATH('row')
);
```

--Now a bunch of replacements

```
SET @intermediateXML=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@intermediateXML,'=',':'),'/>','}'),'<prop1 ','{'),'<prop2 ','{');
SET @intermediateXML=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@intermediateXML,'<customFields>','"customFields":['),'</customFields>',']'),'customfieldid','"customfieldid"'),'customfieldvalue',',"customfieldvalue"');
SET @intermediateXML=REPLACE(REPLACE(@intermediateXML,'<id>','"id":'),'</id>',',');
SET @intermediateXML=REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@intermediateXML,'<row>','{'),'</row>','}'),'}{','},{');

DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX)=N'{"data":{"record":[' +  @intermediateXML + ']}}';
```

PRINT @json;

The result (formatted)

```
{
    "data": {
        "record": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "customFields": [
                    {
                        "customfieldid": "456",
                        "customfieldvalue": "t1"
                    },
                    {
                        "customfieldid": "789",
                        "customfieldvalue": "t2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "customFields": [
                    {
                        "customfieldid": "900",
                        "customfieldvalue": "t3"
                    },
                    {
                        "customfieldid": "902",
                        "customfieldvalue": "t4"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks  we are on 2016 sql server and achieved  very easily over there using JSON  PATH. Will post over here my solution soon

Comment: @Malcolm so why did you tag with sql-server-2008 

Comment: we were first looking out for 2008 only as lot of application are pointed to still 2008 sql server.